# Is $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)=T_qX$ a typographical error?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The following pages are from Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".

[image]

[image]

Is $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)=T_qX$ in the red rectangle a typographical error?

Should $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)=T_qX$ be changed to $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)\subset T_qX$?

Comment: @JackLee Do you think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, this is a mistake, and it's repeated further down the page. (Actually, it's more of a logical oversight than a typographical error.) I've added both corrections to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).

Thanks for pointing this out.